# Find the minimum and maximum of a complex function

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $\Omega :=\{z\in\mathbb{C}: 1\le \vert z\vert \le 2\}$ and $f:\Omega\to\mathbb{R},f(z)=\vert \frac{e^z}{z}\vert$. Determine the maximum and the minimum of $f$.

To find the maximum we need to use the maximum modulus principle, since $f(z)$ is analytic $∀z$ in the region,and $f(z)$ is non-constant, the maximum of this function will be on the boundary of the unit disc.

If we let $z=e^{it}$ then, $$f(z)=\vert \frac{e^{e^{it}}}{e^{it}} \vert=\frac{exp(\cos t+i\sin t)}{(\cos t + i\sin t)}=\frac{e^{\cos t}+e^{i \sin t}}{(\cos t + i\sin t)}=\frac{e^{\cos t}}{(\cos t + i\sin t)}+\frac{e^{i \sin t}}{(\cos t + i\sin t)}$$

after this I'm lost on what to do next, I think that I need to minimise the denominator by choosing $t=0$ which will give a maximum of $e+1$?

How would I then find the minimum of the function?

Comment: It is a real function defined on the complex numbers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the $\max$ must occur on the boundary since $f$ is an open map, but it can be anywhere on the boundary, not just the inner boundary.

Note that $|{e^z \over z}| = {e^{\operatorname{re} x} \over |z|}$.

On $|z|=1$ we see that $\operatorname{re} z \in [-1,1]$ and so the $\max$ is $e$.

on $|z|=2$ we see that $\operatorname{re} z \in [-2,2]$ and so the $\max$ is ${e^{2} \over 2}$.

The $\min$ can be determined in a similar fashion.

It is straightforward to check that ${e^{2} \over 2} > e.$

Comment: The minimum would be $\frac{1}{2e^2}$?

Comment: Yes. Because ${1 \over e} > {1 \over 2 e^2}$.

Comment: Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

On $|z|=r$ we have  $|e^{z}|=|e^{re^{i\theta}}|=e^{r\cos \theta}$ with $0\leq \theta \leq 2\pi$. The maximum value of this is $e^{r}$ and the minimum value is $e^{-r}$. Can you finish?